# OnPress change the style of component from loop- React Native with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

So I am pretty new in react native, I am trying to develop a quiz game, where users will be given Set of answers. I want to select change the color of the component when it is pressed by the user, kind of toggle it. So far I came up with useState solution, but unfortunately cannot figure out how to exclude the change of color, I guess I need to follow indexing or something, can anyone please make me understand the process with the solution.

```
export const QuizScreen = ({ navigation,route }) => {
    const [quizArray, setQuizArray] = React.useState([])
    const [rightAnswer, setRightAnswer]= React.useState(false)
    const [selectBtn, setSelectBtn] = React.useState("#fff")
return(
     <View>
       {quizArray[qno].answer.map(r=>
        <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.listItem, {backgroundColor:selectBtn}]}
           onPress={()=>{
            setRightAnswer(r.rightAnswer)
            setSelectBtn("#DDDDDD")   //so this changes logically all the component from the list
                }}
                activeOpacity={0.6} underlayColor="#DDDDDD"
                    
                >
                <Text>{r.option}</Text>
             </TouchableHighlight>
             
            )}
           </View>
```

I need to know how do i implement the background change for only one and kinda make it toggle everytime user select or deselect. Thank you

Comment: when selected,  background color should be ```#dddddd``` else ```#fff``` ?

Comment: @KetanRamteke Yes, or any two corols

Comment: added the solution, do check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right about using an index for determining the clicked list item.

You can change the color by storing the index of the selected item using selectBtn state and then using that state set the backgroundColor accordingly.

Here is how you can do it:

```js
export const QuizScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [quizArray, setQuizArray] = React.useState([]);
  const [rightAnswer, setRightAnswer] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectBtn, setSelectBtn] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <View>
      {quizArray[qno].answer.map((r, index) => (
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={[
            styles.listItem,
            { backgroundColor: selectBtn === index ? '#dddddd' : '#fff' },
          ]}
          onPress={() => {
            setRightAnswer(r.rightAnswer);
            setSelectBtn(index);
          }}
          activeOpacity={0.6}
          underlayColor="#DDDDDD">
          <Text>{r.option}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here is the working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/smelly-coffee)

[image: Output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYwvl.gif)